# How to create tuple with tokenized text in python?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am new to python need some help in understanding it.

Consider the below spam.csv example

[image]

I have created the tokenized text which contains only character.

```
train['tokenized_text'] = train['V2'].apply(lambda x:([x for x in x.split() if x.isalpha()]))
```

Now ,I want an array of tuples as (tokenized_text,label) How can i generate a tuple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
data = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(df['tokenized_text'], labels)]
```

Comment: Yeah This helps me but when i try to find unique words from this tuple getting unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: why don't you find unique words before converting it into tuple?